# Populate from specific field from the array

Tags: java, android, arrays, populate

I'm trying to retrieve data from a array to a textfield, which is in a listview, right now i have this

```
txtDesignacao.setText(position + 1 + todasAsCategorias.toString());
```

And it's working:

[image]

The thing is, I just want the "Designacao" field, which in this case wold be "Azeites & Outros", how can I achieve this?

##########################Edit

TodasAsCategorias.class:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        String url1 = "something";
        String url2 = "something2";

        for (int idCat = 0; idCat <100; idCat++){
            final String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url1 + idCat + url2);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    String K_PRODUTO = jsonObject.getString("K_PRODUTO");
                    String Designacao = jsonObject.getString("Designacao");
                    HashMap<String, String> cat = new HashMap<>();
                    cat.put("K_PRODUTO", K_PRODUTO);
                    cat.put("Designacao", Designacao);
                    listaCategorias.add(cat);
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    //DO SOMETHING
                }
            } else {
                //DO SOMETHING
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(mContext);
        lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Do Something
            }
        });
    }
}

public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getListaCategorias() {
    return listaCategorias;
}
```

ListViewAdapter.class:

```
@Override
public void fillValues(int position, View convertView) {
    ArrayList array = TodasAsCategorias.getListaCategorias();
    Object todasAsCategorias = array.get(i);
    TextView txtDesignacao = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Designacao);
    txtDesignacao.setText(position + 1 + todasAsCategorias.toString());
}
```

Comment: add the complete code , suggestion override `toString` in your POJO class

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I've added the complete code, or most of it, see if you can help, what I want is to set the TextView txtDesignacao with the contents of the Designacao field in the array

Comment: `Object todasAsCategorias ` should be `HashMap<String, String> todasAsCategorias ` and then `txtDesignacao.setText(position + 1 + todasAsCategorias.get("Designacao"));` , may the force be with you

Answer (score 1):

you have have todasAsCategorias as an object. just todastAsCate.Designacao if it's public property, or todastAsCate.getDesignacao(). All you have to do is check ur todasAsCategorias object